# Get certain attribute of all anchors of certain class

Tags: jquery

I want to get the `name` attribute of all the `<a>` tags with a specific class in jQuery. How can I do it.

Say this is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" name="first" class="myClass">Something</a>
</div>
<a href="#" name="second">Something else</a>
<a href="#" name="third" class="myClass">Something else again</a>
```

So I need to get 'first' and 'third' because they have the class `myClass`. The anchor 'third' doesn't have this class, so I don't need it.

Comment: @sambit.albus, I changed your question so it's more clear what you are asking. Please think about how your question will look to other visitors of SO. It's always nice to include code, and state what you have already tried. Also, make sure your title corresponds to the question (i.e. you didn't mention the fact that you wanted to access an attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use class selector `.` and `prop()` to get the attribute.. `attr()` if you are using old version of jquery (prior jquery 1.6)
try this...

```
$('.className').prop('name'); //calssName is the name of your class
```

for multiple elements

```
$('.className').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).prop('name')) 
});
```

**OR** using `map()`

```
 var nameArray= $('.class').map(function(){
   return this.name;
 }).get();

 console.log(nameArray);  //nameArray is an array with all the names
```

[fiddle usign map](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Zx8/)

example..

```
<a name="test" class="class">test</a>

alert($('.class').prop('name'));
```

Comment: Thanks @bipen how can i access multiple values. is it going to return a array?

Comment: updated please check... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gL5Xf/):

```
$('div.divClass').children('a.anchorClass').each(function( index ) {
    alert($(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new Array();    

$('a.className').each(function(){
   array.push($(this).prop('name'));
})
```

Iterate array to get all attr name of 'a' tag