# Get certain attribute of HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

So I was wondering if there was a way to get e.g. all `value`'s of an HTMLCollection. So something like this:

```js
var users = document.getElementsByName('users')
var userLength = []
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    userLength.push(users[i].value);
}
userLength.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
console.log(userLength);
```

...but in one line, so more like this:

```js
document.getElementsByName('users').value
```

<sub>If you want to run this, it was written for the [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users)-section on [stackexchange](https://www.stackexchange.com). And no, the second one doesn't work.</sub>

I can't use jQuery, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542268/get-certain-attribute-of-all-anchors-of-certain-class) is not an option for me.

Comment: Your example doesn't use `innerText` it uses `value`. Start there. Maybe if you add a [mcve] to your question we can help debug.

Comment: I Guess `map` should be enough here

Comment: Sure you can do it in one line.... delete the returns. :) There is nothing that can do it in one like you want. But map() is the way to go. `document.querySelectorAll("[name='users']").map(x => x.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get element array getting using [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the all the values. Finally chain the *sort* method on the returned results:

```js
var users = document.getElementsByName('users')
var userLength = [...users].map(el => +el.value).sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
console.log(userLength);
```

```html
<input name="users" value="11"/>
<input name="users" value="22"/>
```

Comment: I know this is not really part of the question but is there a way to get the program to return the text like a `document.getElementsByName();`-statement would?

Comment: @gurkensaas, do you mean the value in the string format?

Comment: If I now try to do it with strings, it gives me NaN's. Is there a way to also get strings?

Comment: @gurkensaas, remove the `+` from `+el.value`....i,e: ``[...users].map(el => el.value).sort(function(a, b){return b - a});``